# CKEditor textarea

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, textarea

I have a CKEditor `<textarea>`, but I have a problem when I validate the form. The button validate the test of require just for the first test, but when I repeat with the same test, I find an error. My test my code is:

```
jQuery('#form_parametrage_texte').validate(
            { ignore: [],
                rules: {
                    url: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    texte: {
                        required: function ()
                        {

                            var textLimit = 1;
                            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.texte.getData();
                            jQuery("#value_area").html(str);
                            var txt = jQuery("#value_area").text();
                            var str1 = jQuery.trim(txt);
                            console.log(str1.length);
                            if ((str1.length) < textLimit)
                                return true;

                         }

                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    jQuery(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
                },
                success: function (element) {
                    jQuery(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                }
            });
    jQuery('textarea').ckeditor({toolbar: 'Cms'});
```

Comment: umm..what's the error? what troubleshooting has been done? Please review [ask]

Comment: Post your complete code.